# Why not corned pork instead of beef?

Tags: beef, pork

I have made a few corned beef with chuck and pot roast cuts. Using salt,sugar nitrite salt , etc: the results have been excellent. I have not used brisket because they are so big.  Pork loins and shoulders are so cheap I would like to try corned pork . What could go wrong ?

Answer (score 6):

What could go wrong? Probably not much. The same [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curing_(food_preservation)) that turns beef into corned beef turns pork into corned pork - and if you use another piece and compare recipes, you might recognize the process from curing ham. You might have to compare recipes a bit - curing times ranging from two to ten days depending on the author - and the actual cooking process could require a slightly different timing, but overall, nothing specific to the animal.

And like corned beef, corned pork is sold canned as luncheon meat. The iconic [Spam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spam_(food)) being an (slightly infamous) example.

I even found [one writer](http://yourpotluck.com/Corned_Pork___Cabbage.html) that claims *pork* was actually the more „Irish” version for Irish families (beef being more expensive and mostly exported), while using beef became the American-Irish tradition, resorting to the (Jewish) brisket when beef was actually cheaper and easier to get than pork.

Comment: Wanted to mention Spam and the like too. Also a famous danish label sell what is basically corned pork.

Answer (score 0):

In St.Mary's county Md they have been corning fresh hams for years. You take a fresh ham and put into a brine of pickling spice for 7/10 days than they cut slits in the ham and stuff it with a mixture of greens, Kale,Cabbage,Onion and spices and wrap it up in cheese cloth and place inside a pillow case and place in a large pot and boil for about 18 minutes per pound, remove and let drain good, place in refrigerator for a day or two, unwrap ham and slice thin and serve with some of the stuffing or make a sandwich. For more info look up St Mary's County Md Stuffed Ham recipes.